# Binding Handler that gets the width

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I updated the fiddle.
In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DbJBs/6/) I have 3 divs. In the middle div there are text that loops out.
When the div is to small I want to take out the item and put it in another observableArray that is bound to a select kind of like this.

```
<div data-bind="collection:{items:itemsThatFit,itemsDontFit:itemsDontFit">
   <span data-bind="text:$data"></span>
</div>


<select data-bind="visible:itemsDontFit.length>0, options: itemsDontFit"></select>
```

In the fiddle when you add to many the will not fit so I want it to be moved to the itemsDontFit array.
I having trouble to attack this problem from the right angle and need some help.

I know the fiddle is not near any solution. I just wanted to show that the information inside the div is to big and I want to transfter it to a select.

I also know that I can use the style binding to get the width, but I dont need that on my viewModel so I want to only have it in my bindingHandler.

How do I get a bindingHandler to act as a foreach with the items value?

This is my test now

```
ko.bindingHandlers.collection = {
init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    var value = valueAccessor();
    ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value);
    var $elm = $(element);
    //here I want a foreach on the itemsThatFit
    //maybe add the select in code here?
},
update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    var value = valueAccessor();
    ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value);
    var $elm = $(element);
    //the div width
    var containerWidth = $elm.width();
    //the children width
    var childSum = 0;
    $elm.children().each(function() {
        childSum + $(this).width());
    });

    if(childSum>containerWidth){
       //move last item to itemsDontFit
    }
}};
```

Comment: Have you tried something? There's no code related to your `itemsFit`, `itemsDontFit`. I would start with retrieving the `width` of the element in your ko binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close.

The html is

```
<div data-bind="foreach: developers"> 
  <span data-bind="textWidth:$data, sourceArray:$root.developers,
                   overflowArray:$root.overflow"></span> 
</div>
```

Note that I added the extra bindings at the `<span>` level, not the `<div>`.  This is because it has to check with every `<span>` binding.

The key JavaScript is

```
ko.bindingHandlers['textWidth'] = {
  'update': function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
    // use ko text binding to do actual output.
    ko.bindingHandlers['text'].update(element, valueAccessor);
    var value = valueAccessor();
    ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value);
    var $parentEement = $(element).parent();

    var childSum = 0;
    $parentEement.children().each(function () {
      childSum += $(this).width();
    });

    if (childSum > $($parentEement[0]).width()) {
      var source = allBindings.sourceArray;
      var overflow = allBindings.overflowArray;
      source.remove(value);
      overflow.push(value);
      $(element).text('');
    }
  }
};
```

The updated fiddle is at http://jsfiddle.net/DbJBs/17/